# Windows authentication restrict to specific domain

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, dns

In my asp.net mvc application i use windows authentication. Company has user in multiple domains like "DOMAIN-A\james, DOMAIN-B\james. My application should authenticate only users in "DOMAIN-A". How to fail authentication for other domains users except users in "DOMAIN-A"

Answer (score 0):

It will normally just fail the domain-b users automatically (barring special AD configuration like forest and trusted domains Even then, good luck in getting it to work.)

**It will only authenticate to the domain that the authenticating web server resides in.**

In the case both domains ARE getting authorized, simply check the users name, which will include the domain.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {
        // ensure we have a name and made it through authentication
        if (e.Identity != null && e.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

        }
```

}

Comment: What about adding ActiveDirectoryMembership provider in the web config with desired LDAP connection string. I tried and now it really authenticates users against the domain specified in LDAP connection string. Don’t you think this is a solution?

Comment: No it didn't really work. Now the same user in DOMAIN-A\james and DOMAIN-B\james both get authenticated to the application which I don't want to. How to restrict authentication for specific domain users? Btw, my developer machine is in DOMAIN-A and IIS 7 is configured to use application pool identity.